# Covariant type FParam occurs in contravariant position in type Seq[FParam] of value guesses

Tags: scala, covariance, contravariance, scala-generics

Consider this simple example:

```
trait Optimizer[+FParam, FRes] {
  def optimize(
    fn: (FParam) => FRes,
    guesses: Seq[FParam] // <--- error
  )
}
```

It doesn't compile, because

> Covariant type `FParam` occurs in contravariant position in type `Seq[FParam]` of value guesses.

But seq is defined as `trait Seq[+A]`, so what is the source of this contravariance? (**Question 1**)

Conversely, consider this simple example with `-FParam`:

```
trait Optimizer[-FParam, FRes] {
  def optimize(
    fn: (FParam) => FRes, // <--- error
    guesses: Seq[FParam]
  )
}
```

> Contravariant type occurs in covariant position in type `(FParam) => FRes`

Again, the same paradox: in `Function1[-T1, R]`, the first type parameter is clearly contravariant, so why is `FParam` in a covariant position? (**Question2**)

I can fix this issue by flipping the variance as described in [Lower type bounds](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/lower-type-bounds.html), but why it is necessary is unclear.

```
trait Optimizer[+FParam, FRes] {
  type U <: FParam

  def optimize(
    fn: (FParam) => FRes,
    guesses: Seq[U]
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1**: `+FParam` means the **covariant** type `FParam` and it varies from **supertype** to subtype `FParam`. for the `guesses` it's expecting `cotravariant type` for `Seq`. So you can do it by explicitly stating a `supertype` of `FPParam` for this, like:

```
def optimize[B >: FParam](fn: (B) => FRes, guesses: Seq[B]) // B is the super type of FParam
```

or like the [SeqViewLike](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/05016d9035ab9b1c866bd9f12fdd0491f1ea0cbb/src/library/scala/collection/SeqViewLike.scala#L245).

so for why `guesses` it's expecting `cotravariant type` for `Seq`? for example:

```
trait Animal

case class Dog() extends Animal

case class Cat() extends Animal
val o = new Optimizer2[Dog, Any]
val f: Dog => Any = (d: Dog) =>  ...
o.optimize(f, List(Dog(), Cat())) // if we don't bind B in `guesses` for supertype of `FParam`, it will fail in compile time, since the `guesses` it's expecting a `Dog` type, not the `Animal` type. when we bind it to the supertype of `Dog`, the compiler will infer it to `Animal` type, so `cotravariant type` for `Animal`, the `Cat` type is also matched.
```

**Question 2**: `-FParam` means the **cotravairant** type `FParam` and it varies from supertype `FParam` to it's **subtype**.for `fn: Function1[-T1, +R]//(FParam) => FRes` it's expecting **covariant** type for this. So you can do it by inverse the **Question 1** type state, like:

```
def optimize[B <: FParam](fn: (B) => FRes, guesses: Seq[B]) // B is the sub type of FParam
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that FParam isn't used directly. It is in the argument of `optimize`, and as such its variance is flipped. To illustrate, let's look at the type of `optimize` (see `val optim`):

```
trait Optimizer[+FParam, FRes] {
  type U <: FParam

  def optimize(
    fn: (FParam) => FRes,
    guesses: Seq[U]
  )

  val optim: Function2[
    Function1[
      FParam,
      FRes
    ],
    Seq[U],
    Unit
  ] = optimize
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having [just worked through this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67352479/is-there-a-scala-pattern-for-nested-generics-allowing-my-inner-generic-type-to-h) hopefully I can cut through the confusion.

Seq[] are not lists and cannot have more than one class type at once inside them.  Your trait Optimizer has a unknown but fixed class FParam or a subclass, but your function returning a Seq[FParam] is not bound to be the same subClass as the enclosing object. As such, there could end up a runtime with different subclasses ending up inside the Seq[FParam] at the same time, so the entire code block becomes a Scala compile error.

```
abstract class Optimizer[+FParam, FRes] {

}

object Optimizer{
   def optimize[FParam,FRes](obj: Optimizer[FParam,FRes], param : FParam) : (FParam,Seq[FParam]) = (param,(Nil)) 
}
```

The trait (now an abstract class) still has covariant generic parameters, but the function using that covariance generic in its parameter is type locked to an exact type with an invariant - mandatory the same class or subclass in the function now in a singleton object.